# When IIS applications loads, are application config settings held in memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

When an ASP.NET application loads, are application config settings loaded into memory or read from the disk each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config settings are loaded into memory, but there is a file watch that will reload the settings if you alter the web.config file.